# Administrator privileges

Tags: c++, windows, administrator

This question is linked to [this one.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22359741/c-sharp-ask-once-administrator-privileges/)

How does notebook drivers, which shows information about key combinations on screen, start without asking administrator privileges and under UAC?
How it is possible?

Comment: If your main program runs off of a certain process that does not need elevation, you can create a new process that requests elevation through UAC that handles the installation. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163486.aspx#S9

Comment: If i understand you correctly i can create other program to start first one with administrator privileges?
Or you mean something else?

Comment: @Cyber the link you provided says the user will be prompted for elevation. OP's question is why certain drivers _don't_ require a user prompt but still get privs.

Comment: What would be useful, considering your recent questions, would be for you to tell us what problem you are really trying to solve. As it stands, I suspect you are feeding us a series of XY questions. Tell us the actual problem and maybe you'll get an answer to that problem.

Comment: @David Heffernan I want my c# application(it displays some information about system on screen) be able to run under UAC but without asking administrator provileges every time (that's why I ask about drivers they can do this). And I just want know how. And is it possible for me to do this with my program.

Comment: @York's The point David is trying to make is that you're not asking us the *real* question, just an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/254634). _Why_ do you need admin privs? What are you trying to do that requires those privs?

Comment: @computerfreaker bacause when some programs (for example Task Manager)
are active my program doesn't work(doesn't catch any events and doesn't show any information). But when i run it with admin. privileges everything is good.

Comment: Also I'm sorry for asking X problem (I'm new to stackoverflow) and it's a little bit difficult for me to explain what i want in english.

Comment: The programs you're referring to (installed as part of a driver package, but not themselves device drivers) fall into two classes: programs which don't actually require admin privilege to run, and programs which are injected into the user session by a system service.  I'd hazard a guess that the specific program you're talking about is one of the former cases; it doesn't actually need admin privilege, because all it does is talk to the device driver.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Launching an interactive process as administrator from system service running in standard logged in user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21098315/launching-an-interactive-process-as-administrator-from-system-service-running-in)

Answer (score 1):

Drivers typically run in kernel mode, and so are not subject to UAC. Even drivers that run in user mode are not subject to UAC. Only desktop applications are subject to UAC.

Comment: inb4 "how do I make my program run as a driver?"

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit inb4 "how do I install my program as a driver without requiring admin rights?"